# Nonstop push notifications on recently updated Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, notifications, 4.3-jelly-bean, exchange

My phone received and installed an OTA update this weekend, to Android version 4.3

Now everytime my phone connects to the internet or I go to use the internet, I get this large list of push notifications, of email attachments from my Microsoft Exchange email account, that have never even been downloaded.

I checked the options in the exchange options, and the option to download attachments when connected to wi-fi isn't checked (i've also checked and unchecked it). I also turned off the email notifications for the account, but still get the notifications of the downloaded attachments (even though they are not actually downloading, because you can't even open them).

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Had same problem.  Download manager seems to be the issue if you have that installed.  But just click on one of the notifications, you will see App Info.  Click on that and then unclick show notifications.

It should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable notifications in Play Store.

Open `Play Store` -> look for the three dot `ᐧᐧᐧ` menu -> `Settings` -> Uncheck `Notifications`

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, but seemingly fixed it.

1. Turn off wi-fi temporarily. Only seems to happen to me while connected to wifi (possibly because my email app settings are set to only download when connected to wifi).
2. Go to apps list and find an app called "Downloads".
3. Choose the "Other downloads" tab.
4. Check the boxes for most/all items and click delete.
5. Click the down arrow called "Older" and check all remaining items and click delete.
6. Turn wi-fi back on.

Answer (score 0):

I went into the Download Manager app and once it opened went to the right where it says "Other Downloads" and deleted them all and I rebooted the phone and it seemed to work ok. I havent noticed them coming back or any other issues by doing this as of yet.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I did with that same problem.

1. Settings
2. `More` tab
3. Application manager
4. Scroll right to `all`
5. Select download manager
6. Force stop, and then clear data and cache
7. Reboot

Answer (score -2):

I turned off the sync and turned it back on and the notifications went away.